# laravel 5.7 with() method

Tags: laravel, eloquent, one-to-many

i'm trying to query two related model in the controller but the request failed.
here is my code:

```
$product = 'smartphone';
$prod = Produit::where('designation', $product)->with('tarifs')->get();
foreach($prod->tarifs as $tarif){
 $tarif->prixAchat = $prix[$id];
 $tarif->save();
}
```

this is the error message: **Property [tarifs] does not exist on this collection instance.**

i have this in the Produit model:

```
 public function tarifs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Tarif');
    }
```

and the Tarif model:

```
public function produit()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Produit');
    }
```

Comment: Hmm, are you sure that's the code that produces that error?  I would expect it to say **method** not found with this line: `foreach($prod->tarifs() as $tarif){`  What happens if you remove the `tarifs()` in favor of `tarifs` ?  Also, if you `dd($prod)` before the `foreach`, what does it give you?

Comment: `dd($prod)` : `Collection {#341
      #fillable: array:4 [
        0 => "designation"
        1 => "categorie_id"
        2 => "qte_stock"
        3 => "qte_stock_min"
      ]
      #with: []
      #attributes: array:7 [
        "id" => 2
        "designation" => "Poëlle"
        "qte_stock" => 0
        "qte_stock_min" => 20
        "categorie_id" => 1
        "created_at" => "2020-11-07 09:08:59"
        "updated_at" => "2020-11-07 09:08:59"
      ]
      #relations: array:1 [
        "tarifs" => Collection {#334
          #items: []
        }
      ]`

Comment: there is one relations array with empty tarifs collection

Answer (score 0):

you're getting a collection of products, and trying to get tarifs of it, thats why it throws the error, heres the solution

```
$product = 'smartphone';
$products = Produit::where('designation', $product)->get();
foreach($products as $prod){
   foreach($prod->tarifs as $tarif){
       $tarif->prixAchat = $prix[$id];
       $tarif->save();
   }
}
```

Comment: @A.Rahman , sorry it should be $tarif->update();  not save.

Comment: sorry the tariff table is empty and I believe that is what causes the error. i will fill it and try again